# Assigning a unique code to multiple commandbuttons created with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

Good day,
First post here for me! I couldn't find any answer to my problem even if stackoverflow community has helped me many times this past week to code this project.

Here is what I want to do :
I work as an intern for a big company that makes private jets and I've been asked to find a simple way to find information into a specific table. This table regroups all of the aircrafts sold by the company with particular information regarding each one of them.

As I said, I manage to do a lot thanks to this website but now I have a really particular thing to do.

When a user knows which aircraft to look for, it opens a tab ("RESULTS") with all the information about this aircraft. This is the first search option. It works like a charm!

Here is my excel interface : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXcpY.jpg

But when a user doesn't know which aircraft to look for, he has the option to search for a model or an interior owner (or both) through the User interface ("SEARCH" tab).
The code executes and the sheet "RESULTS2" lists all the aircrafts with a command button in the search column. I've created these buttons with OLEObjects.add and everything worked well.

Now, I need to assign a code to each one of these objects (Commandbutton1, Commandbutton2, ... , CommandbuttonN). 
Everytime the user clicks on a commandbutton, it executes the code of the first search (the one when the user knows the aircraft number) with the aircraft number on the same row.

I have the code I want to execute for each button which would be placed into the "RESULTS2" tab:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Variables
Dim avion As String
Dim lRow2 As Long

'Settings
Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("SEARCH")
Set sourceSheet1 = sourceBook.Sheets("TABLE")
Set sourceSheet2 = sourceBook.Sheets("RESULTS")
Set sourceSheet3 = sourceBook.Sheets("RESULTS2")

'Set "avion" as the aircraft number on the button row ("RESULTS2" tab)
avion = sourceSheet3.Cells(6, "B").Value

'Set the aircraft number on the "SEARCH" tab (User interface) as "avion"
sourceSheet.Cells(5, "E").Value = avion

'Calls the macro to execute search
Call sourceSheet.Searchaircraft

End Sub
```

The result in this particular case would be only for the first row's button (Commandbutton1).

Is there any way to create a Private Sub for ALL command buttons?
Or maybe creating a for loop with :

```
For i=1 To LastRow

    Private Sub "Commandbutton" & i & "_click()"
    [...]
    avion = sourceSheet3.Cells(i+5, "B").Value
    [...]
    End Sub

Next i
```

For your information, here is the part of the code in the "SEARCH" tab which creates the commandbuttons (it is inside a for loop to create each line) :

```
'Bouton
            Set rng = sourceSheet3.Range("G" & n)
            Set mybutton = sourceSheet3.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
            rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            With mybutton
                .Object.Caption = "<->"
                .Object.Font.Size = 3
                .Left = rng.Left + 1
                .Top = rng.Top + 1
                .Height = 11.75
                .Width = 60
            End With
```

Any help from you would be really appreciated!
This thing is driving me nut since a few hours...!

Thank you and have a nice day,
Alex

---

EDIT :

Nutsch's answer was the one!

Here is the code I wrote in a module :

```
`Public Sub WhichButton()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdNewTerm_Click

'Variables
Dim avion As String
Dim ButtonText As String
Dim b As Object
Dim Ligne As Integer


'Settings
Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("SEARCH")
Set sourceSheet1 = sourceBook.Sheets("TABLE")
Set sourceSheet2 = sourceBook.Sheets("RESULTS")
Set sourceSheet3 = sourceBook.Sheets("RESULTS2")


'Vérification de quel bouton a été appuyé
Set b = sourceSheet3.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        Ligne = .Row
    End With


' Récupération du numéro de l'avion
avion = sourceSheet3.Cells(Ligne, "B").Text

' Inscription du numéro dans la page SEARCH
sourceSheet.Cells(5, "E").Value = avion

'Calls the macro to execute search
Call sourceSheet.Searchaircraft


' Fenêtre en cas d'erreur de programmation
GoTo Exit_cmdNewTerm_Click

Err_cmdNewTerm_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdNewTerm_Click

Exit_cmdNewTerm_Click:

End Sub
```

And here is the code in my sheet to add buttons :

```
'Bouton
Set rng = sourceSheet3.Range("G" & n)
sourceSheet3.Buttons.Add(rng.Left + 1, rng.Top + 1, 60, 11.75).OnAction = "WhichButton"
sourceSheet3.Buttons.Caption = "Search"
```

Hope this will help someone one day.
Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same macro for all buttons and use application.caller to find out which button was pressed.

Comment: Ok, I think I undesrtand now what you're suggesting, I'll try it right now! Thanks!